# Azure ML SDK in Python, Azure ML models to integrate in Notebook

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

We are setting up Azure ML SDK in Python. When we are creating models using Azure ML SDK in Python notebook We have to manually write the code to use feature of Azure ML and Scikit learn-- But if we model in ML studio we will do all that easily by drag and drop. Required solution is Can we build a model in Azure ML Studio and use the model in Azure ML SDK (Python Notebook). No more manual coding for Model creation will be involved. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Yes currently it's in road map to export an Azure ML Visual Designer flow into a python code. Use a graphical user interface in order to generate automatically the python code will be available in near future.

Answer (score 0):

@Ram mentions going from UI to Python SDK, but I recommend investigating the opposite direction with `ModuleStep`s in the SDK. If you can package your code into Modules, they can be called with Modules, which are on the roadmap to be made available within the visual designer.